# SVG loads differently depending on how i access my webpage

Tags: html, css, url, svg

So I have this webpage, and I set an SVG to scale to width 100% of its parent div (which has position: absolute), and when I open it from the directory it is stored on, it is fine; however, when I open it from its url on the internet, it looks all zoomed in, and has scroll bars to "navigate" the large svg image.

```
#titlebar   {
    top:0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

This code makes the SVG scale down to the width of the parent div when accessed from a file drive such as file:///T:/public_html/..., but makes scrollbars and leaves the SVG size like the original, and has scrollbars to navigate it when accessed through its url.

Comment: also I'm using an <object> tag because an <img> tag also doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding the `viewBox` attribute to the SVG that you are including. 
It is generally used to scale SVG's based on the parent width and height. 
Read this for more information : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox

Comment: so i put viewbox: 0 0 100 100 and that didnt work. how do i put the viewbox in percentage of the parent div?

Comment: Viewbox generally is relative to the parent width and height. 
Read this to understand the 4 properties of viewbox - http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-viewport-view-box.html.
Could you make a fiddle or provide some more code ?

Comment: so i have <div id = "main">
 <object  id = "titlebar" data = "TitleBar.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style="viewbox:0 0 100 100"> </object>, with the CSS #titlebar {
 top:0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 preserveAspectRatio: xMinYMin meet;
 viewbox:0 0 100 100;
}

Comment: ah! i understand now -- i had to put the viewbox and preserveAspectRatio attributes in my svg files and not the object tag which encased the svg. it works now :)

Comment: Ohh yes, it has to be in the SVG. 
Glad it worked for you :)